# maxima and converting output of variable to float

Tags: equation, equation-solving, maxima

I can get maxima to solve an equation but can't figure out why it won't show it's numerical value without typing the extra command/step of **float(%)**.   Is there away to automatically convert a solved variable to a numerical format.

Example of equation below:

```
kill(all); alpha:float(.0014931); endfreq:50; dursec:1200; solve(alpha=log(startfreq/endfreq)/dursec,float(startfreq));
```

what comes back is
**startfreq=50%e(44793/25000)**

I would like it to say **299.988** instead

Comment: Cross posted to Mathematics Stack Exchange: [maxima and converting output of variable to float](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736585/maxima-and-converting-output-of-variable-to-float)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Maxima prefers exact results (i.e., integers, rational numbers, and symbolic constants) instead of inexact (i.e., float and bigfloat numbers). If you want to work only with numerical solutions, take a look at `find_root`. E.g.:

```
(%i1) [alpha, endfreq, dursec] : [0.0014931, 50, 1200] $
(%i2) find_root (alpha = log(startfreq / endfreq)/dursec, startfreq, 1, 500);
(%o2)                          299.9881594652534
```

Note that to use `find_root` you must know an interval (here 1 to 500) which contains a root of the equation.